# What is the best word to describe the feeling of being nervous, intimidated, excited etc which may be felt upon meeting a person you greatly admire?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, phrase-requests, emotions, contradiction

Every time I've had the opportunity to meet a moviestar/rockstar who I idolize and imitate in every way (and call it influence), I always flub it up. Without fail. This is because I get so nervous and I want so badly to strike up a rivetting conversation that I lose my ability to talk, or even think.

But still, somehow, I muster up the courage to approach my personal epitome of awesomeness, trusting my social instincts will kick in by the time I actually try talking to him. But the closer I appproach, the blanker my mind grows. Eventually I reach a proximity that forces him to acknowledge my intention to speak to him; and so he makes eye contact with me, waiting.

I can't just tell him how much I love his music, being just like every other annoying fan. But still... that'd be better than what I was actually being like: some weirdo who walks up and stares with mouth agape and eyes wide, as if staring into the ark of the covenant, manifested in the form of Cedric Bixler the vocalist of 2 revolutionary post-punk/screamo bands as well as half the reason why hipsters wear skinny jeans.

It was the most painfully awkward 30 seconds of my life and it took years of psycho therapy to finally heal from the trauma caused by my Oscar winning portrayal of Captain Awkward.

But what I'm really needing to know ASAP would be the perfect word and/or phrase to describe that feeling that left me speechless? It was kind of like an amalgamation of being nervous and feeling privileged to be in the presence of such an amazing human being. It's similar to words like intimidated, overhelmed, daunting, honored, umworthy, nerve wracking, mind-blowing, formidable, impressed, flustered, veneration, revery, dazed, bewildered, dumb-struck, and of course, nervous or privileged.  But I feel like there's yet another pseudosynonym that embodies the precise meaning of this word that is lodged within my subconscious state of awareness, beyond the reach of my self-awareness. Whatever that perfectly descriptive adjective is, I'll know immediately upon hearing it. It will possess all the expected connotations, implications,
and inspirations that are conjured when I unsuccessfully attempt to recall this ellusive adjective (presumably. It may turn out to be any variety probably combination of words, but used in such a way to describe a complex emotional state)

The reason I'm asking is because I have, by a stroke of luck, become engaged in an online conversation with a member of the royal family of a very rich nation. (it is a long term convo: days or weeks btwn replies) noooo it is not the Prince of Nigeria. I was skeptical at first but he seems to only be interested in the human connection and has said nothing suspicious. But I was trying to be appropriately humble as I suspect civilians are expected to be towards royalty in his culture, and I was trying to say that it made me nervous but immensely grateful at the same time to be in conversation with such a person as his lordship. But I juSt could not find the exact right word. Help me to ingratiate this genuinely regal fellow who may possibly become another one of my many friends in high places. Thank you

The exact wording of the sentence that I am planning to use this yet to be determined adjective is as follows:

"I must admit it is rather  __________ to be conversing with royalty."

I might say "a bit" instead of "rather."

If I can not find my perfect descriptor, I will just be forced to describe the 2 juxtaposed emotions separately. I've already written a rough draft as a back up just in case the unimaginable happens and it turns out I'm hunting a word that doesn't exist. Here it is:

"I must admi it is a bit intimidating to be conversing with royalty. However, it is also a great honor. I feel very fortunate that..."

I think using "a bit" makes it less formal. And I don't wAnt to address him as MY prince, but rather A Prince that I happen to be friends with. So I am trying to maintain a careful balance between formal and casual types of parlance

Comment: 'Star-struck', given in the previous thread.

Answer (score 2):

Are you starstruck? Or would that be too informal for royalty? Awe-struck? Over-awed?

Comment: Star-struck was my thought, but this answer would be improved by a definition (e.g. from a dictionary) and examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about **fantastical**?

> strange and wonderful, like something out of a story:
>
> - *Fantastical Buddhist temples and medieval castles cling to Bhutan's misty valleys.*

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fantastical)]

But please note that this word doesn't encapsulate feelings of intimidation, which you'd mentioned in your question. Still I think it is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am rather sure that no single word term can be found to express exactly this state of mind, and even that no single phrase will be adequate to fulfill this aim.

The following descriptive terms can be collected in the text.
*"get so nervous" …  "I lose my ability to talk… think"

"amalgamation of being nervous and "feeling privileged to be in the presence"

"intimidated, overwhelmed, daunting, … umworthy, nerve wracking, mind-blowing, formidable, impressed, flustered, veneration, revery, dazed, bewildered, dumb-struck, and of course, nervous or privileged , honored,"*

The collection of the states of mind  described  in the text of the question sift down to seven affections of the mind that it is inconceivable to consider as all impinging simultaneously in a human's mind, although, if considered as experienced in some sequence, they are not at all an unimaginable nor impossible combination. Nevertheless, no  extant single word term can connote exactly all those seven ideas. The best that might be done would be to approximate the whole to a general idea that is compatible with all aspects considered.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1. nervous | "get so nervous", "amalgamation of being nervous", "nerve wracking" |
| 2. awed | "mind-blowing, formidable, impressed," |
| 3. unworthy | "unworthy", |
| 4. incapacitated | "I lose my ability to talk… think", "dumb-struck", "dazed", "bewildered", |
| 5. looked upon with favour | "feeling privileged", |
| 6. fancying | revery |
| 7. praiseful | "veneration" |

The nervousness, awe, unworthiness and incapacitation are easily associated with felt smallness; the feeling of being looked upon with favour can also be associated with felt smallness, even if it is not always the case that favours are gained from the more powerful. As well, the praisefulness is quite compatible with a would-be felt smallness; the praise of the religious for their god is proof to that. What can't be "explained" easily in the reality of "felt smallness" is the fancying, although this is not so unrealistic from a consideration of the spiritual life of the saints (of whose spiritual stance felt smallness and praise are characteristic).
So, a term expressing this felt smallness can be considered, but, most preferably, it should make abstraction of the physical reality covered by the concept and bear on the spiritual and intellectual facet.
The phrase "mind dwarfing experience", which I think idiomatic, although without a perfect certitude, seems to gather this general idea of felt spiritual and intellectual smallness.

- I must admit it is rather a mind dwarfing experience to be conversing with royalty.

Nevertheless, after such a summing up statement I would expand somewhat in the way it is done in the text of the question, as this phrase can't carry all the specificity found in that text.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth analysis. I'm considering your idea the feeling of being small (in comparison) and upon reading your example of my sentence with "mind dwarfing" inserted, I realized that a similar word/phrase , "mind blowing" would probably work. I've never actually used the word "mind dwarfing" so it might come off unnatural. But on the other hand "mind blowing" might not be formal enough. Also it doesn't imply nervousness. But now I'm thinking about maybe using "out of my league" It might be the best word that makes all the right insinuations. Thanks for the pointers